# Embedded Fonts Won't Appear

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-player-11

I'm trying to embed a font in FlashDevelop. My folder structure is

[image: FlashDevelop Folder Structure]

My embed metadata is

`[Embed(source = 'resources/04B08.TTF', fontName = '04b08')] public var _04b08:Class;`

My code is

```
    public var titleFormat:TextFormat;
    public var titleText:TextField;

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        // entry point
        titleText = new TextField();
        titleFormat = new TextFormat();
        titleFormat.font = "04b08";
        titleFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        titleFormat.size = 72;

        //titleText.embedFonts = true;
        titleText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        titleText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;
        titleText.defaultTextFormat = titleFormat;
        titleText.text = "TEST";

        titleText.x = 10;
        titleText.y = 10;

        addChild(titleText);
    }
```

If I use this, I get

[image: TEST]

But I uncomment the `titleText.embedFonts = true;` line, I get

[image]

This is the method that all of the guides I can find use. What should I do to get it to work?

Comment: after `fontName = '04b08'` put `,embedAsCFF='false'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try  a method [registerFont()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#registerFont%28%29) before using it:

```
import flash.text.Font;
Font.registerFont(_04b08);
```

Also, try other metadata parameters like `embedAsCFF='false'` and `fontFamily='fontName'`, and then use `titleFormat.font = "fontName";`.

For more reliably testing don't have the font installed in your OS.

Comment: `embedAsCFF` is the right answer here. Check out http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass for the full description of getting it working